# paper.js and javascript 'this' confusion

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Hi I am creating a Cabinet object in javascript and I am trying to access the objects property inside paper.js' onFrame function... But when I use 'this' inside the onFrame function I can not access the object property:

```
function Cabinet(){
    this.spine = new Path({x:0, y:0});
    this.draw();    
    return this;
}

Cabinet.prototype = {
  draw:function(){
    view.onFrame = function(event) {
      this.spine // trying to access Cabinet object but this is not referring to    Cabinet object
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It may help to read some good articles on *this*, the one at [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Simply save the value of `this` in a variable:

```
Cabinet.prototype = {
  draw:function(){
    var cab = this;
    this.spine.onFrame = function(event) {
      cab.spine // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only solution?

Comment: @ratata no, there are other ways to achieve the same effect, but this is probably the simplest way to do it. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: No the answer is ok. I voted up. But is there a better way? ( it can be the hard way too )

Comment: @ratata the `.bind()` approach mentioned in the other answer is another way to do it, though `.bind()` is not available in old versions of Internet Explorer so you have to provide a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the function so that `this` becomes a reference to the Cabinet object.

```
Cabinet.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    view.onFrame = function(event) {
      this.spine;
    }.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: "Scope"? Neither *bind* or *this* are about scope.

Comment: Correct. Typing to quick.